# How do I restrict hours of operation in a rest-based API function?

Tags: amazon-web-services, rest, aws-lambda, postmates

I have an API integration for our web store running on AWS Lambda to return live delivery quotes based on customer address, and then create the delivery order to a third party delivery as a service provider when the invoice is completed (paid).

I was able to add a time restriction for Monday-Saturday but Sunday has different hours and is not working. Here is the relevant code:

```js
    'use strict'

    /**
     * This function is use to generate qoutes to client 1st warehouse
     */
    exports.handler = function (event, context, callback) {
        console.log('-------------------EVENT OBJECT--------------------------')
        // console.log(event.body.shipping_address)
        console.log(event)
        try {
            const app = require('./app')
            const EventEmitter = require('events').EventEmitter
            const _bus = new EventEmitter()
            let date = new Date()
            if (date.getDay() == 0) {
                if (!(date.getHours() >= 17 && date.getHours() <= 22) || !(date.getHours() < 3)) {
                    callback(null, {
                        message: 'The store is closed'
                    })
                }
            } else {
                if (date.getHours() >= 3 && date.getHours() <= 15) {
                    callback(null, {
                        message: 'The store is closed'
                    })
                }
            }

            let _shipmentReturn = []
            let _shipmentReturnError = []
        }
        catch(e) {

        }

    }
```

Comment: On Sunday your store is open between 17-22 and after 3?

Comment: Concurring sort of with Umar. What hours do you want the service to work? Additionally, a catch without doing anything with the error is a very bad idea. Let the lambda error out

Comment: Side-comment: Please note that AWS Lambda environments use `UTC` as the timezone. You will likely need to convert this into your local timezone. Your code would read cleaner if you use your local times. Also, beware of Daylight Savings, which might also impact your timezone conversion.

Comment: Yes, Saturday we are open until 9pm, the server is 6 hours ahead so technically it should be open until 3am. On Sunday we are open 11am(+6=17) until 5pm (22)

Comment: Saturday we are open from 10am-9pm. In server time (+6), that is 16 (Sat) to (3) Sun, the next day.  Sunday we are open from 11am-5pm or 17 (Sun) to 23 (Sun). To fully express Sunday I'd have to say it's open (on server time) from 0-2, closed from 3-16, open from 17-22 and closed from 23-24.

Answer (score 1):

Be very careful when using `NOT` logic.

Your 'normal' days have the store **closed** from 3am to 4pm. (Yes, 4pm. That's because you only check hours, so 3:59pm is still an 'hour' of 3, so it would be closed.)

On Sunday, the store is closed from midnight to 4:59pm, and also 10pm to midnight.

Take a look at this line:

```js
if (!(date.getHours() >= 17 && date.getHours() <= 22) || !(date.getHours() < 3)) {
```

Let's pick a time of 2am. It equates to:

```js
if (!(FALSE) || !(TRUE))
```

This equals TRUE, so the store is closed.

Same for 4am: `if (!(FALSE) || !(FALSE))` also equals `TRUE`

You possibly want an `AND` rather than an `OR` in those logic statements.

I would also recommend that you **convert the `UTC` times into your "local" times**, which would make it easier for you to write the logic. This will avoid errors where UTC Sunday does not actually align to your 'local' Sunday. For example, if you are UTC-6, then 2am UTC Sunday is *not* Sunday in your timezone.

Comment: A lot of the confusion (my self included) has been around the time zone adjustment and the double NOT statements.   

Your 'normal' days have the store closed from 3am to 4pm. (Yes, 4pm. That's because you only check hours, so 3:59pm is still an 'hour' of 3, so it would be closed.)  

This is correct 3am - 6 = 9pm which is when our store closes. 4pm - 6 = 10am when we open.